# datetime.strptime Format does not match format '%d. %B %Y'

Tags: python, date, datetime, timestamp, strptime

I want to convert type of string date to other format which as dd-mm-yyyy

```
date_stringg='24. Juli 2020'

date_object = datetime.strptime((date_stringg), "%d. %B %Y")

print("date_object: ", date_object)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific issue? What do you understand from that error message? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to set the locale. `Juli` is not a valid month name in english language, I'm assuming it is Dutch.

Assuming you want to use the Dutch locale with datetime, you can do the following

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "nl_nl")
```

After that, it will recognize `Juli` so this will work

```
>>> date_stringg='24. Juli 2020'
>>> 
>>> date_object = datetime.strptime((date_stringg), "%d. %B %Y")
>>> date_object
datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a locale setting problem. See the example below:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')
'C'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('24. Julho 2020', '%d. %B %Y')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '24. Julho 2020' does not match format '%d. %B %Y'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_PT.utf8')
'pt_PT.utf8'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('24. Julho 2020', '%d. %B %Y')
datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 24, 0, 0)
```

You may need to select (and maybe install/configure your underlying system) for the language you are using in the strings you want to parse.
In the example you see I wrote the string 'Julho' (July) in Portuguese, so the proper locale has to be active.

See also the Python documentation on [setting the locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html?highlight=setlocale#locale.setlocale)